# In a list of data frames, calculate proportion of these that meets a condition

Tags: r, loops, indexing, bioinformatics

I have a list of data frames (`gtf`) and I would like to calculate what proportion of each of these data frames have 0's at a set of coordinates [i,j] (coordinates [i,j] == 0). i.e. if I have 500 data frames and 120 of them have 0 at coordinates [1,1], then the function would return 120/500.

Eventually, I would like my function to return a data frame where the columns correspond to the columns of `gtf` and the values are the proportions of data frames that had 0's in the corresponding coordinates. Here is a recreation of `gtf`:

```
x = matrix(c(1,0), 6,6)
x = as.data.frame(x)
y = matrix(c(0,1), 6,6)
y = as.data.frame(x)
gtf = list(x,y,x,y)
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
for (i in seq_along(gtf)) 
    for (j in seq_along(gtf[[i]])) 
        if (gtf[[i]][1,j] == 0) tf[[i]] <- TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert the `list` elements to logical matrix using `==`, `Reduce` it to a single dataset by adding the corresponding 'i,j' elements and divide by the `length` of the `list`

```
Reduce(`+`, lapply(gtf, `==`, 0))/length(gtf)
```

Comment: I really need to start learning these `reduce` and `apply` functions more thoroughly. Is there a tutorial you could recommend?

Comment: @eabrown2378 May be this link helps for [apply](https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/)